# CocoaPods setup too slow, how to set proxy in terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, proxy, terminal, cocoapods

When I use terminal to 'setup' or 'update' cocoapods, I find it needs a lot of time to fetching.

So I'm wondering whether there is a way to set a proxy to my terminal, so that it return result more fast?

Comment: I think, pod server or your internet is slow. update don't take toomuch time

Comment: How many minutes you need when you 'update'? My net speed is 10M, but I still need about 10 minutes to 'update'

Comment: less than minute..something is wrong...can you paste your pod file?

Comment: platform:ios, '6.0'
pod 'BlocksKit', :git => 'https://github.com/pandamonia/BlocksKit.git', :branch => 'next'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.0.3'
pod 'AMScrollingNavbar','0.5.1'
pod 'iRate','1.9.2'
pod 'Reachability', '3.1.1'
inhibit_all_warnings!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Choice 1

Step 1:

From Google choose a proxy

Step 2:

Set up the proxy to your Mac

Step 3:

In your terminal set proxy with your port:

```
export http_proxy='http://your_proxy:8000'
```

Choice 2

```
pod repo remove master
pod repo add master https://gitcafe.com/lloydsheng/Specs.git
pod repo update
```

Choice 3  Recommend

```
pod install --verbose --no-repo-update
```

Comment: Choice 2 and 3 cannot save your time because pod install still pulls source code from github, which is sometimes interrupted by the gfw. You then will get an error. I think choice 1 is the best one among your answer.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I found that it was stuck at "analyzing dependencies" because of an error on my Podfile.

Try this:

```
pod install --verbose
```

Comment: you can use my mirror [specs](http://akinliu.github.io/2014/05/03/cocoapods-specs-/)

Comment: @kgpdeveloper Can this be use to add proxy to wkwebview?

Answer (score 4):

```
pod install --verbose --no-repo-update
pod update --verbose --no-repo-update
```